# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm opening a text file and trying to write it to an SQL database.

```
import mysql.connector
import sys
import mysql

f = open('norepeats.txt', 'r')

def sniffertodatabase(f):
for line in f:
    linestrip = line.strip()
    IP = linestrip
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='', password='', host='localhost', database='snifferdb')
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    #print IP
    insert_stmt = (
    "INSERT INTO SNIFFERDBIPs (IP)"
    "VALUES (%s)"
    )
    data = ('IP')
    cur.execute(insert_stmt, data)

    #cur.execute("INSERT INTO SNIFFERDBIPs (IP)" "VALUES (%s), (IP)")
    #cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (42, 'bar'))
    cnx.commit()
    cnx.close()
sniffertodatabase(f)
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "snifferdatabase.py", line 26, in <module>
  sniffertodatabase(f)
File "snifferdatabase.py", line 19, in sniffertodatabase
  cur.execute(insert_stmt, data)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 480, in execute
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: your `data` should be `('IP',)`; it's _str_ now, but you need _tuple_

Comment: I didn't post as an answer, so that's ok; by the way, you're creating and closing a connection for every line in your file, you should do it only once, which would be better

Answer (score 6):

You have `data=('IP')`. Even though you put it in brackets it is not treated as a tuple. See this:

```
>>> type(('IP'))
<type 'str'>
>>> type(('IP',))
<type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

So you need to change your `data=('IP')` to `data=('IP',)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list instead of a tuple that way you can do

```
data = ['IP']
```